# How to fully reset Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras in conjunction with scikit-optimize, which means that for every iteration of the later, a new Keras model is created, trained and tested. It worked fine until I started using reccurent models with GRU (or LSTM) cells. Now after the first iteration (which completes without an issue) I get the following error :

```
  File "C:\...\my_script.py", line 157, in <module>
    n_calls=bayesian_iterations, x0=default_parameters)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\gp.py", line 228, in gp_minimize
    callback=callback, n_jobs=n_jobs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\base.py", line 253, in base_minimize
    next_y = func(next_x)
  File "C:\...\my_script.py", line 121, in compute_cost
    model = train_model(args,X_train,y_train,n_epochs=n_epochs)
  File "C:\...\my_script.py", line 96, in train_model
    activation='elu',alpha=alpha,l2_alpha=l2_alpha)
  File "C:\...\my_script.py", line 63, in create_model
    x = GRU(units=n_neurons,activation=activation,return_sequences=True)(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 499, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 1628, in call
    initial_state=initial_state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 564, in call
    if len(initial_state) != len(self.states):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 401, in states
    num_states = len(self.cell.state_size)
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

At the moment I use:

```
K.reset_uids()
K.clear_session()
```

Although I didn't use `reset_uid()` before using recurrent network and it worked fine, I only tried it to see if it improved my situation but it didn't. I don't think this is normal behaviour but I need a quick solution, and I think if there was a way to completely reset Keras it would work (since it works on the first iteration with no issue). I tried using `from importlib import reload` then `reload(keras)` but it didn't change (although I import Keras modules separately using `from keras import something` so I don't know if this changes that). I couldn't find a way to fully reset Keras hence my question here.

Comment: Please post some code: I am fairly sure there is something wrong in your code (looks like you are using stateful RNNs or something like that) that is causing wrong evaluation